# Fortran copy of pointer

Tags: pointers, memory, fortran

I have a type var that contains a pointer p.
I need to copy var on another variable var1 of the same type as var (by doing var1 "=" var, in quotation because I do not know if it is the correct way, see below).

In my implementation var and var1 are passed to a subroutine that needs to initialise var1 to var and then modify var1. 
If I change the values of var1%p, then var%p is modified as well.
So, I need to change the values of the memory zone pointed by var1%p, without modifying the memory zone pointed by var%p.
What is the correct way to do that in Fortran (2003, Intel) ?

Code example:

```
type variable 
     real, dimension(:), pointer:: p
end type variable


subroutine init(var,var1) !This of course will not work
  type (variable):: var, var1
  var1=var
end subroutine
```

Now, I need to be able to do something equivalent to changing var1%p without affecting var%p. I cannot change variable (I am modifying existing code).

---

Following solution below (if I am correct):
I declare var1 as:

```
Type(variable), allocatable:: Var1
```

then allocate and initialize:

```
allocate(var1, source=var) 
var1 = var
```

Then

```
call somesub(var1)
```

that modifies var1%p, has the consequence to modify var%p such that var%p is equal to var1%p.

Edit 3:
    Doing:

```
 subroutine init(var,var1)
 type(variable), intent(in):: var
 type(variable), allocatable, intent(inout):: var1
 allocate(var1%p, source=var%p)
 var1%p = 2 
 end subroutine init

 type variable:: var
 type variable, allocatable:: var1
 call init(var, var1)
```

The above compiles but crashes (hangs infinitely).
Using instead:

```
allocate(var1, source=var)
```

runs but updates var%p to 1.

Comment: Do you have some minimal code you could show us, to ensure that we fully understand your question?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess: you're probably better off using allocatable arrays for what you are trying to do than pointers and their targets.  If two pointers point at the same 'memory zone' then of course changing the contents of the (one) memory zone will affect what the two pointers point at.  You want to have the pointers point at different memory zones, though probably containing the same contents at the same time the second pointer is associated.  But your question can't really be answered without code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark    Question updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do an intrinsic assignment of derived type variables, any pointers are copied using pointer assignment `=>` (which just copies the address and other properties of the existing piece of memory). You must make sure a new target is allocated in memory and the value of the array is copied there.

You can create your own overloaded assignment for the given type and than use the syntax `var1 = var1`, or you can code the proper assignment into your subroutine, if it suffices:

```
subroutine init(var,var1) !This of course will not work
 type(variable) :: var, var1  !DO NOT FORGET THIS WHEN POSTING EXAMPLES NEXT TIME!

 allocate( var1%p(lbound(var%p,1):ubound(var%p,1)) )

 var1%p = var%p
end subroutine
```

As HighPerformance Mark commented, if you do not have other reasons to use pointers, allocatable components are MUCH better.

```
type variable 
     real, dimension(:), allocatable :: p
end type variable


subroutine init(var,var1) !This WILL work
  type (variable):: var, var1
  var1 = var
end subroutine
```

---

In your edit you have the same problem:

```
var1 = var
```

That is exactly the same problem as before, you didn't change anything!

Also

```
allocate(var1, source=var)
```

should have the same effect as the original code, I believe you need

```
allocate(var1%p, source=var%p)
```

but I already commented that most common versions of gfortran will not accept that and will require the shape to be specified explicitly.

The variables `var` and `var1` do not have to be allocatable. But they can be, if it is required for some other reason.

---

It is possible to write the user defined assignment once and then overload the intrinsic assignment (`=`).

```
   type variable
     real :: pointer :: p(:)
   contains
     procedure :: assign
     generic :: assignment(=) => assign
   end type

   subroutine assign(out, in)
      class(variable), intent(out) :: out
      class(variable), intent(in) :: in

      allocate( out%p(lbound(in%p,1):ubound(in%p,1)) )

      out%p = in%p
   end subroutine
```

Then you can write `var1 = var` whenever you want and it will call the subroutine `assign` automatically.

Comment: I will have to use the solution with pointers. If  p is an (a pointer to an) array of n dimensions, is there a more compact way to allocate var1%p to the size of var%p ?

Comment: Well you could try `allocate(var1, source=var)` which hardly needs a subroutine at all.  But it does need an up to date compiler.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the versions of gfortran I use still require the shape to be specified explicitly, even when `source=` is used. I am not sure about the most recent version.

Comment: If the array always starts at 1 then `allocate( var1%p(size(var%p)) )` is shorter.

Comment: @Henry Why don't you simply use the first code I offered when you struggle with the sourced allocation?

Comment: @VladimirF I get the error:"The rank of the allocate-shape-spec-list differs from the rank of the allocate-object", anyway this method is not satisfactory as I have to allocate manually all the members of var1, instead of a unique allocation with source.

Comment: @Henry But you HAVE TO allocate each member if they are pointers! There is NO other way! That's why are allocatables so much better. You can place it to a subroutine, but you have to do it. As to the error message, did you read it? Check that you allocate it with correct dimensions.

Comment: Yes, you wrote: allocate( out%p(lbound(in%p,1):ubound(in%p,1)) )  Imagine I have 20 pointers in the class, I am not going to write that 20 times.

Comment: You write them ONLY ONCE in the overloaded assignment. THERE IS NO OTHER WAY.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway for your help and your patience.